# Fitting certain problems into the mold of Twelvefold Way

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I have been going through Daniel Marcus' list of standard counting problems and fitting them into the framework of Twelvefold Way(TW), but I got stuck at the

> Standard Problem #$13$: Find the number of distributions of a set of distinct balls into a set of distinct boxes, if no boxes can be empty.
>
> Standard Problem #$14$: Find the number of words of a given length from a given set of letters, if each letter must occur at least once in each word.
>
> Standard Problems #$13$ and #$14$ are equivalent.

Looks like the function used in the problem #$13$ is $f: \{\text{distinct}\} \to \{\text{distinct}\}$ where $f$ is surjective. In the table for TW, that cell is occupied by the formula $n!S(k, n)$ where $S$ stands for Stirling.

According to Marcus the solution to problem #$13$ is $\sum \binom{m}{m_1,\ldots,m_n}$ where $m_i \ge 1$ and $\sum_{i=1}^nm_i = m.$ Does this sum solve the same problem as $n!S(k, n)$? If not where does the problem #$13$ fit into TW and how is it different from the problem that is solved by $n!S(k, n)$? Where can I read up on problems similar to #$13$? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it does, but the first formula is usually more convenient.

To turn Problem 13 into Problem 14, imagine that the $n$ boxes are labelled with the letters, and the balls are labelled $1...k$ to represent positions in the word of length *k*.

$S(x,y)$ is a Stirling number of the second kind, which counts the number of ways to put the $x$ members of a set into exactly $y$ equivalence classes. Then $y!$ assigns labels to the classes.

The $m$ in Problem 14 corresponds to the $k$ in Problem 13. Each solution of $\sum m_i=m$ corresponds to one way of deciding how many of each of the *n* letters will appear in the word. Then the multinomial counts the distinct arrangements for that particular choice.

Search for "Stirling numbers of the second kind" for similar problems.